# How to call same API multiple times with different request in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular9

In my application where I have an array of objects. when I start clicking on a button, I have to call an API. here every object in my array should be as a payload request for the API. so I have to make API call multiple times for each object in the array. if any API call is failed it should stop the loop or process and if we start again from the failure one. once it completed all the objects in the array, the loop or process stops.

can anyone help me out with how to achieve this in angular rxjs

Comment: Have you tried anything, in code? If so, how exactly is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I believe you would want to do something like this in your ts pages

```
// Query Service Class (qs): What will be handling the call
private apiSubject = new ReplaySubject<ExpectedResultFormat>(1);
// Query Service Class (qs): What will be handling the response
private apiResults = this.apiSubject.asObservable();

// Query Service Class (qs): Your API call would call the subject passing in the results
this.apiSubject.next(apiQueryResults);

// A different class: What will be subscribing to the results Query Service (qs)
private sub_apiResults: any;
this.sub_apiResults = this.qs.apiResults.subscribe(resultsObj => {
    YourBL
})

// I prefer to use a variable to the subscribe in order to clean up memory on destroy
...
this.sub_apiResults.unsubscribe();

// All of your components that need to call the same API would just listen for the results. You could essentially put the same format in each component file e.g.
private sub_apiResults: any;
this.sub_apiResults = this.qs.apiResults.subscribe(resultsObj => {
    YourBL
})
```

Comment: Not clear now on if you are trying to call and cancel the prior requests or if you are trying to make multiple calls to the same end point or if you are wanting to call same api with various payloads and handle each individual call.